# How do I use StepObjects with Cests?

Tags: codeception

How do I use a StepObject with a Cest? The documentation only gives a StepObject with a Cept example. It appears I need to instantiate a StepObject with the $scenario, but the only argument the test is provided is the *Tester.

Answer (score 2):

A little nugget in the docs:

> Each public method of Cest (except those starting with _) will be executed as a test and will receive Actor class as the first parameter and **$scenario variable as the second one**.

You can use this `$scenario` argument to create a StepObject inside of your test like so:

```
class AddTaskTest
{
    public function login(AcceptanceTester $I, $scenario)
    {
         $I = new AcceptanceTester\UserSteps($scenario);
         $I->login('test@example.com', 'password');
    }

    /**
     * @depends login
     */
    public function tryToAddATask(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        /** Steps to create a task here after you've logged in **/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the above program that you are given and the output showing as

```
Functional Tests (2) -------------------------
Before (suiteCest::before)
Scenario:
 PASSED

Try to test (suiteCest::tryToTest)
Scenario:
 PASSED
```

Without opening browser the command line says all scripts are passed.

Comment: The `tryToAddATask()` I made in my answer does not have any methods in it. If you have a `UserSteps` StepObject with a `login()` method just like mine, but no code inside, then yes the browser will have nothing to do.